# It is possible to add extra button under the 'publish' button in the post of wordpress? and how?

Tags: posts, buttons

Actually i need such a function , when we click on the "publish" button of the post in word press, after publish automatically go this page on the desired link()..

2nd :if we add a button "return link " just bellow the "publish" button ,then also i can get this function.. my question is how how to solve this problem and how we add button on the wordpress post under the publish button?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add another button to the admin page.

Download the [MetaBox](http://metabox.io) plugin 

Create a file called "button.php" in the wp-content folder
Inlcude "button.php" in functions.php
In button.php, type:

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'admin_button_register_meta_boxes' );

function your_prefix_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {

    $prefix = 'admin_button_';

    $meta_boxes[] = array(

        'id'         => 'standard',

        'title'      => esc_html__( 'Standard Fields', 'admin_button' ),

        'post_types' => array( 'post', 'page' ),

        'context'    => 'side',

        'priority'   => 'high',

        'autosave'   => true,
        // List of meta fields
        'fields'     => array(
             array(
                'id'   => 'custom_html',
                // Field name: usually not used
                // 'name' => __( 'Custom HTML', 'admin_button' ),
                'type' => 'custom_html',
                // HTML content
                'std'  => ' ',

            ),
           ),
      );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

Now you have a form controlled by the button. Depending on what you want to do with the button, you can have a PHP method check to see if the form was posted or you can have the button trigger a javascript event.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to go to a newly published post-

`function wpse248883_post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
    wp_safe_redirect( $permalink );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'wpse248883_post_published_notification', 10, 2 );`

And for a new button, use this-

`add_action( 'post_submitbox_start', 'wpse248883_new_button' );
function wpse248883_new_button(){
    ?>
    <div>
        <input name="save" type="button" class="button-large button-primary" value="New Button" />
    </div>
    <?php
}`

It'll add a button **above** Publish button.